# C# timer starts automatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't know why my timer starts automatically. Maybe anybody can help?

```
public int sek;
void TextBox1TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sek = sek+Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);           
}

void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = Convert.ToString(sek);
    timer1.Start();
}

void Label2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

void Timer1Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = Convert.ToString(sek);
    if (sek==0){
        Console.Beep(1000 ,500);
        MessageBox.Show("Times is out");
        timer1.Stop();
    }           
}
```

Comment: How and where are you declaring your `timer1` ?

Comment: in design i declare timer1

Comment: Is it's `Enabled` property set to true?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yes ,its set to true

Comment: @eatmailyo there's your problem.

Answer (score 5):

This can be caused if the [Timer.Enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property is set to true by the designer:

> *Setting Enabled to true is the same as calling Start*, while setting Enabled to false is the same as calling Stop.

So don't set it - that is, leave it False - in the designer properties.

---

Note: For a WinForms application, [sub-]controls are initialized and properties are set (according to the designer) in the applicable "InitializeComponent" method. This can be verified by viewing the <form>.Designer.cs file.

Answer (score 5):

The `Enabled` property of a timer indicates if its currently running or not.

Since you have that property set to `True` in the designer, you timer starts out in the running state. Simply set it to `False` so it starts stopped.

Sample image provided by @GrawCube:

[image: property box]

Answer (score 0):

Since your using a winforms timer, you would need to set its initial state to disabled or it will start ticking immediately.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx